# CSS animation to pulse section of image

Tags: css, html, css-animations

I'm using CSS animation on a simple image.
I want the pulse animation only to target part of the image.
How I can make that pulse animation so that only the text "Trello" changes opacity?

Here is my code:

```css
.element {
  /*animation-delay: 2s;*/
  animation: pulse 3s infinite;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  margin-top: 50px;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://d78fikflryjgj.cloudfront.net/images/50b4ebc64391dc394a38e73aed57f0e2/header-logo.png" alt="" class="element" />
```

[View on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpdLje)

Comment: If your trying to make the 'Trello' pulse and not the icon next to it, you are going to need to use two separate images and just throw the pulse animation on the image with the text.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is there anyway to make same animation with only one image? If there is no way to make that way, then I just make it with two images.

Comment: Not sure why this is in the edit queue - looks good to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this example for both. I hope it's helpful to you.

```css
.pulse {
  animation: pulse 3s infinite;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  margin-top: 50px;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  animation-name: pulse;
}
    
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
    
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://d78fikflryjgj.cloudfront.net/images/50b4ebc64391dc394a38e73aed57f0e2/header-logo.png" alt="" class="pulse" />
```